# Unison: Ignore files with Regex doesn't work

Tags: regex, unison

I tried to ignore some files that end with ".NUMBERS" like `.133443`. I tried this Regex but it still copies the files:

```
unison -batch -owner -group -times -ignore "Regex ^*\.[0-9]+$" /hadoop/bigdata/giin/data ssh://cnp31ginhortonen1.giin.recouv//hadoop/bigdata/giin/data -prefer newer`
```

**Source :**

```
[root@cnp31ginhortonen1 .unison]# tree /hadoop/bigdata/giin/data/ 

/hadoop/bigdata/giin/data/
├── aefd.csv
├── aefd.log
├── aefd.xml
├── subdir
│   ├── aefd.csv
│   ├── aefd.log
│   ├── aefd.xml
│   └── TB5E.B01.117.210409074
├── TB5E.B01.117.10409074
└── TB5E.B01.117.210409074
```

Comment: There is an error in your regular expression. You likely meant to write: `^.*\.[0-9]+$`. Note the dot _before_ the asterisk. Another tip: Is there any way you could make your regular expression more specific? Like leading subdirectories, double file extensions (I note you have multiple file extensions in your example), ... As it is written, your regular expression will make `unison` skip man pages (extensions `.1`, `.2`, ...), and perhaps other files you didn't mean to skip (backups, data files, ...).

Comment: thanks your regex worked :) `^.*\.[0-9]+$`

Comment: Still doesn't work for me. @anis: were you trying to ignore core dumps?